# Error al asignar el valor por defecto a parametros de entrada

Tags: sql-server

estoy intentando asignar a el parametro de tipo fecha un valor por defecto pero no me esta dejando:

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE DATOS(
            @FECHA_INICIO  DATE = "1-01-2000",
            @FECHA_FIN DATE = "12-31-2010")
 AS 
  BEGIN
     SELECT *
     FROM Socios
    WHERE Fecha_nacimiento BETWEEN @FECHA_INICIO AND @FECHA_FIN
   END
```

Error al convertir una cadena de caracteres en fecha y/u hora.
Quiero que tenga ese valor por defecto como podria hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza el formato universal para pasar los datos por parámetros:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DATOS(
            @FECHA_INICIO  DATE = "20000101",
            @FECHA_FIN DATE = "20101231")
 AS 
  BEGIN

     print @FECHA_INICIO
     print @FECHA_FIN

   END
```

El formato universal es "yyyyMMdd" AñoMesDia

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Según la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/data-types/date-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) debes colocar la cadena de texto en formato `YYYY-MM-DD`, aplicando lo anteriormente dicho quedaría así:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DATOS (
    @FECHA_INICIO DATE = "2000-01-01",
    @FECHA_FIN DATE = "2010-12-31"
)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Socios
    WHERE Fecha_nacimiento BETWEEN @FECHA_INICIO AND @FECHA_FIN
END
```